# Geometry problem - Triangles and angles

Tags: geometry

This is an example from my book that I am currently studying. The explanation was given, but I can't understand the explanation. I need some help regarding this -

Q. In the figure given below, $\overline{AD} = \overline{CD} = \overline{BC}$. What is the value of $\angle CDB$?
[image]

In this figure, those $x$ and $y$ was written in explanation, and those were not part of the question. I understood the explanation, but **while explanation why the author made out that $\angle ACD$ is half of angle $\angle CDB$**. It's apparent that $\angle CDB = \angle CBD$.

Answer (score 1):

Since triangle $ACD$ is an isosceles triangle, then $\angle CAD$ = $\angle ACD = x$. So $\angle ADC = 180^\circ - 2x$.

Since $ADB$ is a straight line, we have $\angle CDB = 180^\circ - \angle ADC = 180^\circ - (180^\circ - 2x) = 2x$.

Hence, $\angle CDB = 2 \angle ACD$.

Comment: I understood that. It was present in the explanation, but I need to know wht it's x and 2x? Because those were not mentioned in the question. How is it made out 2x and x? Please explain that

Comment: Hold on, let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\angle ADC = 180 - 2x$. Now since ADC has two sides of equal length we know that $\angle DAC = \angle ACD$ so that $\angle ACD = \frac{1}{2}(180 - \angle ADC) = \frac{1}{2}(180 - (180 - 2x)) = x$.

Comment: So we conclude that $\angle ACD = \frac{1}{2}\angle CDB$.